# Error when using foreach loop to filter data dynamically based on user selection from dropdown list in cshtml

Tags: model-view-controller, razor, dynamic, foreach, model

I am trying to using foreach loop to get data that is filtered dynamically. I have a dropdownlist and after user select the year from it, the selected year will be used as filter to show data in the foreach list.

1. the dropdown list:
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedYear, new SelectList(Model.List.Select(x => x.Year).Distinct()), new { @id="ddlYears"} );
2. use javascript to get variable @seletedYear assigned with the selected dropdown value:        $(document).ready(function () { $('#ddlYears').change(function () { selectedYear = $('#ddlYears :selected').text(); }); });
3. foreach loop to select the content based on the selectedYear:
   @foreach (var item in Model.List.Where(i => i.Year == @selectedYear))

I am always getting the error on the foreach loop" the expression tree may not contain dynamic operation" Any idea? Appreciate your time and help!